# Check user permissions works in plugin but produce error in admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wrote a small plugin that check user permissions and send corresponding JSON to ExtJS client.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Check gallery user
Description: Check gallery user
Version: 1.0
*/

if (strpos(__FILE__, 'check_manage_options.php') !== false) {
    require('../../../wp-load.php');
    $manage_options = 'no';
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $manage_options = 'yes';
    }
    $perms = array("perms" => array("perm" => $manage_options));
    echo json_encode($perms);
}
?>
```

With ExtJS it works correctly. But when I try to come on "/wordpress/wp-admin/" URL, I've get error:

> Warning: require(../../../wp-load.php) [function.require]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\CheckGalleryUser\check_manage_options.php
>   on line 9
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '../../../wp-load.php' (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\CheckGalleryUser\check_manage_options.php
>   on line 9

Also I tried another approach:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Check gallery user
Description: Check gallery user
Version: 1.0
*/
add_action('init', 'check_gallery_user');
function check_gallery_user() {
$manage_options = 'no';
if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    $manage_options = 'yes';
}
}
$perms = array("perms" => array("perm" => $manage_options));
echo json_encode($perms);
?>
```

Then I get such error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\CheckGalleryUser\check_manage_options.php
>   on line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below approach

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Check gallery user
Description: Check gallery user
Version: 1.0
*/

function cgu_init() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['cgu_check'] ) && 'check' === $_GET['cgu_check'] ) {
        $manage_options = 'no';
        if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
            $manage_options = 'yes';
        }
        $perms = array( "perms" => array( "perm" => $manage_options ) );
        echo json_encode( $perms );
        die();
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'cgu_init' );
```

And then when you send request just send it to `http://your-site/?cgu_check=check`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in Z:\home\localhost\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\CheckGalleryUser\check_manage_options.php on line 21

Comment: When do you get this error? After plugin activation or maybe during ajax request?

Comment: It was when I tried to come on "/wordpress/wp-admin/". But now I found another solution based on your idea.

Comment: I am just curious how do you access this plugin? Do you send request to `http://your-site/wp-content/plugins/CheckGalleryUser/check_manage_options.php?cgu_check=check` or just `http://your-site/?cgu_check=check` as the second URL should not produce any warning / error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I sent request to http://my-site/wp-content/plugins/CheckGalleryUser/check_manage_options.php?c‌​gu_check=check  Now I send it to http://my-site/?cgu_check=check and it works. I will use your solution.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. When you call check_manage_options.php directly then it doesn't behave as WordPress plugin - just a regular PHP file and that's why you had to include wp-load.php script. I suggest using scripts in WordPress context to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Check gallery user
Description: Check gallery user
Version: 1.0
*/
if ( isset( $_GET['cgu_check'] ) && 'check' === $_GET['cgu_check'] ) {
    require('../../../wp-load.php');
    $manage_options = 'no';
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $manage_options = 'yes';
    }
    $perms = array("perms" => array("perm" => $manage_options));
    echo json_encode($perms);
}
?>
```

In addition I have set output_buffering = On in php.ini because this code caused an  "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" warning on "/wordpress/wp-admin/" URL.
Thank you!